# trying to generalize the spectral theorem as it is stated in my textbook

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, symmetric-matrices

If $(\mathbb R,V,+,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ is a finite-dimensional inproductspace and $L:V\rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation with matrix-representation $A$ that is symmetric with respect to some basis of $V$. Does the spectral theorem hold in this situation? And why (not)?

I'm asking this because I'm trying to generalize the spectral theorem as it is stated in my textbook, which, if I understand it correctly, assumes that $A$ is a symmetric matrix-representation of $L$ with respect to specifically the standard basis of $V=\mathbb R^n$ (or any orthonormal basis, it's unclear). It says that in this section that it is dealing with "symmetric transformations on a Euclidean space. If we're working with coordinates with respect to an orthonormal basis then this comes down to transformations of $R^n$ that are describable by a symmetric matrix." But it doesn't explain what 'symmetric transformations' are, why the matrix-representations are symmetric with respect to an orthonormal basis, etc.

You may generalize it further to Hermitic spaces if you are first of all capable of answering my questions clearly. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like your textbook (which really should be defining its terms) is talking about a [self-adjoint operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator). An operator $T : V \to V$ is self-adjoint if, for all $v, w \in V$, $\langle Tv, w \rangle = \langle v, Tw \rangle$. This is equivalent to the matrix representation of $T$ being Hermitian under some orthonormal basis (and you may replace "some orthonormal basis" with "all orthonormal bases" at your leisure).

Comment: The property of having a Hermitian matrix representation under some (not necessarily orthonormal) basis, is actually equivalent to being diagonalisable.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. So having a Hermitian matrix representation is equivalent to being diagonisable, and having a Hermitian matrix representation with respect to an orthogonal basis with vectors of the same length (from the first answer to my question) is equivalent to having a diagonal matrix representation with respect to a orthonormal basis, then?

Comment: Sorry, I should amend my previous comment a little: having a Hermitian matrix representation is equivalent to having a **real** diagonal matrix representation. If any of the eigenvalues are non-real, then a Hermetian matrix representation is impossible. As for your second query, yes, that's correct, provided (once again) that you specify that it's a *real* diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 1):

No. You need a matrix representation with respect to an orthogonal basis with vectors of equal length, perhaps not $1$.

Take the matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
representing a linear map on the plane with respect to the basis $v_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $v_2=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Then the standard matrix of $A$ (i.e., the matrix with respect to the standard basis) is
$$B=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 2 & -1\end{bmatrix}.$$
As you can check, the eigenvalues are $-1$ and $3$, with corresponding non-orthogonal eigenvectors $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 2\\1\end{bmatrix}$.